# Обособлять ли деепричастный оборот?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

***С опаской и поворачиваясь ежесекундно то в одну, то в другую сторону, ему удалось уйти незамеченным.***

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в данном предложении? Как я понимаю, наличие запятой после однородных членов предложения, соединенных повторяющимися союзами "то", зависит от автора, то есть: запятая ставится для смыслового выделения или для выражения попутного пояснения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки правильные. Но деепричастные обороты не присоединяют союзом "и".

Правильная структура предложения должна быть без "и" - оно лишнее:
*С опаской поворачиваясь ежесекундно то в одну, то в другую сторону, ему удалось уйти незамеченным.* || "С опаской" по смыслу примыкает к обороту.

Запятая ставится перед вторым "то", как и в случае с повтором союза "и".
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=329
По Розенталю, при союзе "и" запятую можно было бы опустить:
*Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила **и в ту и в другую сторону**.*

После "в другую сторону" деепричастный оборот заканчивается и ставится запятая.

Comment: Союз "и" в предложении соединяет необособленное обстоятельство (с опаской) и деепричастие, выступающее в роли однородного члена предложения с этим обстоятельством

Comment: А если деепричастие или деепричастная конструкция окажется внутри повторяющихся союзов, изменится ли пунктуация?     Например: Тимофей следовал за ним (,) то прихрамывая, то идя быстрым ходом (,) и думал о своем. Ответьте, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые, взятые скобки?